# Is there an easier way to check if this proposition is a tautology?(other than truth tables)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How do I show that ((p→q)∨(r→s))→((p∨r)→(q∨s)) is a tautology?

I came across this problem, spent quite some time on it and it seems there isn't a way to check if this proposition is a tautology or not.

Comment: Here's a hint: $(p \vee r) \rightarrow (q \vee s)$ is equivalent to $(p \rightarrow (q \vee s)) \wedge (r \rightarrow (q \vee s))$.

Comment: I think it should be easy, write p→q as ~(p^~q) every where and then use demorgan law:~A or~B is just~(A^B)

Comment: @ali, that works mechanically but relies on excluded middle, and I'd say it's not the most intuitive approach in terms of what the expression actually means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false; just think about what it means.

The statement says that, given $p \rightarrow q$ OR if $r \rightarrow s,$ you want to prove $p$ or $r$ implies $q$ or $s.$

With an or statement like $p$ or $r,$ break it up into two parts: First assume $p$ is true, then assume $r$ is true.

If $p$ is true, we want to prove $q$ or $s.$ There's no way of proving $s$ from $p,$ so we have to hope to prove $q$ using $p\rightarrow q.$ But now we see the problem: What if $p \rightarrow q$ is false, and $r$ is false?

For instance, take $p$ to be True, $q$ to be False, $r$ to be False, and $s$ to be False. Then $r \rightarrow s$ is True, but $(p\lor r) \rightarrow (q \lor s)$ is True implies False, which is False.

Comment: One can also reverse the order (assume $r$, then assume $p$). In that case the counterexample obtained has all terms false except $r$. (Of course, only one counterexample is needed.)

Comment: Please stay clear of answering very low quality questions like the one you just answered.  It's a violation of the Enforcement of Quality Standards.  First, prior to answering, suggest ways the asker can improve their question.  Anyone can answer such questions, with little or no skill involved. Try to answer the legitimate questions, if you can.